# how to know if a date/time falls in some date/time range?

Tags: php

For example I have a date/time range which doesn't have year, and which needs to be converted to timestamp like below,

```
<?php
    $dateStart = '11-28 00:00:00';
    $dateEnd = '11-28 23:59:59';
?>
```

Now I want to get the current date and time of the user and check if it falls inside the given date range or not. How do I do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this logic:

```
$start_date = '2012-07-10';
$end_date = '2012-10-06';
$date_from_user = '2009-08-28';

checkInRange($start_date, $end_date, $date_from_user);

function checkInRange($start_date, $end_date, $date_from_user)
{
  // Convert to timestamp
  $start_timestamp = strtotime($start_date);
  $end_timestamp = strtotime($end_date);
  $user_timestamp = strtotime($date_from_user);

  // Check that user date is between start & end
  return (($user_timestamp >= $start_timestamp) && ($user_timestamp <= $end_timestamp));
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Will this `strtotime()` method work even after I remove the year from the given date ? And what about the time ? Thank you for your time.

Comment: In case of time, just append the start_time, end_time, etc with the time string like this - `2012-07-10 00:00:00`

Comment: Okay. and how do I get the current date and time of the user through php ? Sorry for the trouble. For example, get the date and time of the user who is using the website from Japan or USA or any other place ?